# Shared library in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

Basically what I want to do is the following:

I have a `Core.cpp` that loads shared libraries (SDL lib, Ncurses lib, and Qt Lib)...

Here's the `main`:

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
  {
     Core                  *core;
     LibGestionnary        gestionnary;
     IDisplay              *display;
     display = gestionnary.loadLibFromName(std::string(argv[3]));
     display->Boucle(core);
  }
```

And here's the interface, from which the DisplaySDL, DisplayNcurses and DisplayQT inherits:

```
#ifndef IDISPLAY_HH__
# define IDISPLAY_HH__

#include "../Core/Core.hh"

class IDisplay
{
public:
  virtual ~IDisplay() { }
  // virtual void dispSnake(Snake snake) = 0;                                   
  // virtual void dispBlock(Block block) = 0;                                   
  // virtual void dispMap(Map map) = 0;                                         
  virtual void Boucle(Core *core) = 0;
  virtual void displayEnd(Core *core) = 0;
};

#endif
```

I can easily load my `libsdl.so` and `libndk.so`, and everything's working great.
The thing is, that Qt need `argc` and `argv` in order to create the `QApplication`.

How can I achieve to do this, knowing I don't have access to `argv` and `argc` in my shared libraries?

Comment: Do you need the ``QApplication`` var? If not, just don't create it.  Then you won't have the ``QApplication`` message loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `QApplication` needs `argc` and `argv` to look for Qt-specific options, and to determine the application path. If you don't want to parse these options from your real command line, you can construct your own `argc` and `argv` to pass to the `QApplication` constructor.